# 14.04 update problem with executable file mode

Tags: scripts, perl

Here's the problem:

1. I create a file called foo.pl containing `#!/usr/bin/perl` as the top line
2. I execute `chmod u+x foo.pl`
3. I type `./foo.pl` at the command prompt and get the following

   ```
   bash: ./foo.pl: Permission denied
   ```
4. `foo.pl` at the command prompt issues the same error

The execute bit on the fill is set

```
-rwxrw-r-- 1 myname mygroup 73 Sep  4 12:29 foo.pl
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm assuming your username is, considering the obfuscation, `myname`? Is this file on a partition other than root partition? Also, you probably meant to say you ran `./foo.pl` (I've edited your question).

Comment: actully, neither foo.pl nor './foo.pl' work; same error both times. And yes, the username and group are correct

Comment: Okay. Are you the owner of the file? Are you `myname`? And is this file on a different partition than root? The partition that it is on could have the `noexec` mount option on it. You can verify that by looking at the options on the partition from the command `mount`.

Comment: Is the filesystem in which foo.pl is located mounted as noexec? If you don't know how to do this already, use `mount` or `cat /proc/mounts | column -t`

Comment: Set permission as 'executable' for all(sudo chmod +x foo.pl).Hope it helps!Or you can set $PATH to your present directory and run only foo.pl after executing "chmod +x foo.pl"